# Setting width dynamically angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to set width dynamically.
I have tried:

```
iElement.find("#mycontent").css({width:iElement.width()+ 'px !important'});
```

In html:

```
<div id="mycontent"></div>
```

I am trying above syntax to get width on the div's id "mycontent".
When I alert IElement.width(), i have the exact value. But when i add the above code, width is not setting on element or anywhere. I dont understand, why it is not working.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with angular model.

```
<div id="mycontent" style="width:{{myWidth}}px; height:400px; background-color:black"></div>
```

And now you can adjust the width by varying the model `$scope.myWidth`.

Or you can simply adjust it from the html page itself.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myWidth" />
```

**Edit**

And also you can set `ng-style` directive to set width dynamically.

```
<div ng-style="myStyle" >
```

And now you can set your width in the model `myStyle`.

For example, you can set it's width on a button click,

```
<button ng-click="myStyle = {'width' : '100px'}"> Set a width </button>
```

Hope this will help you.

Please feel free to ask any doubts about this as comment.

Comment: It's better to use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) instead.

Comment: Thank you Remco, Actually I am not aware of `ng-style`. I am a beginner. Thanks once again to correct me and guide me to correct answer.

Comment: @Abhilash P A :
I set the scope of myWidth in js file. It is ng-style="width:px;

Comment: @prashanth, how do you set your model? `$scope.myWidth = 100;`?

Comment: @Abhilash P A I get it from directive.js file.
var hasContent = iElement.find("#mycontent");
     if (hasContent) {
      scope.myWidth = iElement.width();
      alert("width: " + iElement.width());
      alert("scope width " + scope.myWidth);

     }

Alert has exact values.

Comment: @AbhilashPA yes. Since the width value is dynamic

Comment: @prashanth, could you please provide code for custom directive? And also, how do you change your `scope` variable from your directive?

Comment: @AbhilashPA directive('portalFooterWrapper', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
                var hasContent = iElement.find("#mycontent"); if (hasContent) { scope.myWidth = iElement.width(); alert("width: " + iElement.width()); alert("scope width " + scope.myWidth); }
            }
        };
    })

Comment: Hi @prashanth, you are assigning value to your model `myWidth` to a scope of directive only, not your controller's scope. You can pass your controller's scope model to directive and set it from directive.

Comment: @prashanth assume your directive is `<portal-footer-wrapper width-model="myWidth" > </portalFooterWrapper>`. here you has to initialize your model within your controller like `$scope.myWidth=100;`

Comment: @prashanth, And modify your directive as, `return { restrict : 'E', scope : { widthModel : '='  }, link : function(scope, iElement, iAttr){  scope.widthModel = 200; } }`. Here you can see that you are passing a scope model to your directive and now you can update your controller model `$scope.myWidth` from your directive.

Comment: @prashanth Now you can change you width by changing value of `scope.widthModel`'s value from your directive.